# Leitura de células com fórmulas HLOOKUP

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi

Estou a ter dificuldades em avaliar uma fórmula com a API Apache Poi numa célula que contém a fórmula `HLOOKUP(B9,$AK$8:$AS$68,2,FALSE)`.

Acontece a mesma coisa seja um ficheiro `.xls` ou `.xlsx`.

A folha de excel tem uma *tabela template* que vou preenchendo com determinados valores que vêm doutro sitio. As células da primeira e da segunda coluna dessa tabela são strings. as células seguintes são números, e a última célula é a fórmula que mencionei lá em cima - `HLOOKUP(B9,$AK$8:$AS$68,2,FALSE)` - e é essa que não consigo ler o valor.

Depois de preencher, consigo fazer o `get` e o `set` de todos os campos, mas quando vou avaliar a fórmula no `switch` vou parar sempre ao `Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR`:

```
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = my_xls_workbookp.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("R9");
        Row row = my_worksheetp.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
        Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());
        int cellType = evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);

        switch (cellType) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                break;
                // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never happen
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
                break;
        }
```

Uma curiosidade: Não sei se ajuda mas se depois de colocar os valores, abrir o Excel através do Office, não fizer nada no documento, e voltar a fechar, aparece-me a mensagem do Office a dizer:

> As seguintes funcionalidades não podem ser guardadas em livros sem
>   permissão para macros: A Função do excel 4.0 armazenada nos nomes
>   definidos. Para guardar um ficheiro com estas funcionalidades, clique
>   em Não e, em seguida, seleccione um tipo de ficheiros com permissão
>   para macros na lista tipo de ficheiros. Para continuar a guardar como
>   um livro sem permissão para macros, clique em Sim.

Em escolho a opção "Sim" e se depois disso eu for ler o ficheiro, já consigo fazer o `getNumericCellValue()` e obter o valor, mas isso não me interessa porque eu tenho de obter o valor quando estou a escrever.

Será que esta API não consegue ler os `$AK$8:$AS$68` directamente, terei que fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: Olá @Oliveira, sobre a mensagem ao fechar ele apenas informa que não consegue gravar caso não utilizem a extensão '.xlsm'. Sobre a função o 'cellType' é visto como célula como um todo (todos os campos e opções no xml do Excel) portanto ele traz como fórmula... nunca usei essa função, mas tente colocar o 'TypeFormula' antes do 'TypeError', caso não dê certo, teste colocar no 'TypeError' para buscar como 'String' 'Case Error' e veja se traz o número conforme desejado, se sim, podemos buscar uma forma de tratar a informação antes de fazer a busca dos dados.

Comment: Em todo caso, @Oliveira, pode-se fazer uma função antes de rodar essa função, fazendo um colar valores na coluna desejada e então rodar essa função.

Comment: No próximo fim de semana vou experimentar isso que me disseste.. mas continua a ser estranho já conseguir ler o valor se preencher o Excel no Java, abrir o ficheiro e gravar após aquela mensagem.

Comment: Realizei alguns testes e comigo funcionou normalmente. Você está lendo essa fórmula de uma planilha ou você está criando a planilha. Disponibilize a planilha ou o código que gera a planilha para facilitar a identificação do problema. De todo caso, se a fórmula for resolvida com sucesso, o código entrará no CellType do tipo do resultado. Você está pegando o CellType do retorno do método evaluate. Se você quiser entrar no case  do Type_Formula, você teria que utilizar o CellType do Cell.

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir um caso em que a execução entre no Type_Error. No meu caso, quando a fórmula está incorreta é lançada uma exception to tipo FormulaParseException. Estou utilizando o poi na versão 3.17.